# Loading PHP Success message in Lightbox/Modal

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a basic understanding of PHP, and in the past, have always loaded my "thank you for submitting/success message" info in an exterior php/html file.

Currently I'm using Zurb.Foundation to build a site and was wondering how I can load a success message inside a modal I'm already using on the page?

It's not currently active, but here's an example to reference (click 'submit' to see modal):
http://www.josephsjoblom.com/clients/nhcw/contact.html

This is what I've typically done in my php file when all is good with the form:

```
/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: ../thanks.html');
exit();
```

Can I just use something like this?:

```
header('Location: #link_to_an_ID_example');
exit();
```

Does anyone know how to do something like this or have an example link?

Thanks

Comment: I already posted an answer, but after re-reading your question, I'm confused.  Do you want to do this in jquery, as your tag suggests, or in Foundation?

Comment: Foundation using the data-reveal feature. Assuming there are no errors, and the form is entered correctly, once you hit submit I want the php to capture the form info then pop the "success" dialog. The link I attached is showing how I want it to work, it's just not capture the form info at this point. Does that help? Happy to explain more in depth in needed.

Comment: I'm happy to use jquery though if I can still pull off the form capturing and popping the data-reveal modal when successful. I was planing on doing in-line errors most likely using jquery so fine by me if you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you could tweak to your purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.quickLyric").click(function(){ 
    // capture the url to load from the id 
    var urlLoad = $(this).attr("id"); 
      // load the second template with AJAX
      $("div[class="+urlLoad+"]").toggle();
      $("div[class="+urlLoad+"]").load('/songs/inc/'+urlLoad+'/');
    // just make sure the page doesn’t reload 
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

Source: http://expressionengine.com/archived_forums/viewthread/113886/